# Can I post Excel formulas for review here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to get a review on some Excel (Non-VBA) data validation formulas I have applied to some columns in a spreadsheet. Is this acceptable? I feel like it will get closed on SO because I'm really looking for input on some limitations I'm experiencing in Excel.

Also, what I'm trying to accomplish is really simple (ensure duplicates don't exist across several rows) and probably doesn't need any test data, but if I had to provide some test data, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Short answer, yes. You should still ensure it covers all the bases that regular code reviews require, working formula, etc.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, you can make [tables using MathJax](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3911/9357).

Comment: Sweet. I checked but couldn't find a duplicate before posting so it may be helpful to keep this around for questions that use "Excel" instead of "spreadsheet"

Comment: I really recommend looking at the main site question linked in my meta question. The Mug did a great job of making it a good question. It wasn't in that state when it arrived.